# Finding a code snipplets in a binary file

Tags: regex, algorithm, context-free-grammar

I have binary file of ASCII garbage that contains, let's say, some snipplets of XML code somewhere in it.

*I looking for a (preferably fast) algorithm that can find these XML snipplets in this binary file.*

(Just like regex, but do the pattern matching with a context free grammars.)

I would like to generalize the algorithm somehow for other context free grammars as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why does it have to be a CFG? Why isn't a relatively simple regex enough? Do you know something about the XML (e.g. the name of the root tag)?

Comment: Because you cannot parse XML with regex.

I said XML just for an example, actually I have the grammar and a parser for Javascript, and looking for javascript codes hidden in binary files.

Comment: You know the snippets / fragments that you want to recognise / detect ? How many do you want to detect simultaniously ?

Comment: No I don't know anything about the snipplets, the only thing I know is the grammar.

Comment: Have you tried the unix utility `strings`? Also, a "binary file of ASCII garbage" is a contradiction in terms. Which is it, binary, or ASCII?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the parser will parse a sentence that should belong to the language, not an arbitrary sentence where the one(s) belonging to the language are hidden inside of it.

I suggest that you use the start symbol of your grammar and regexes to check for it in the ASCII garbage and once you have found it, to use your parser on the text starting at that symbol with the rest of the sentence and see where the parser stops parsing with an error. Then you'll have to figure out if the JS code is good or not depending on where the error happens.

I don't know any algorithm that does what you want right out of the box but I guess that someone might have had the need for this before because it is useful actually. Maybe you could find something interesting inside the book [Parsing Techniques](http://www.amazon.com/o/asin/1441919015) by Grune and Jacobs.